# I want to write a function that takes a list and returns in ascending order with out using the sort built in function

Tags: python

I have tried this, but the problem is i dont know how to make the program compares each element with list to determine its order

```
a= [1,4,8,2,210,3]
def sorting(L):
for i in L:
    if i[0]<:
        print i[0]
sorting(a)
```

Comment: `if i[0] < *what*`?

Comment: What's the problem with the sort function ? Please..Don't look for your home works answer here. !

Comment: You need to look at any sorting algorithm then things will be clear.

Comment: The [list of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) is quite exhaustive.

Comment: So you want to implement your version of sort? There are plenty of resource out there. e.g. http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/01/basic-sorting-algorithms-implemented-in-python/ You just need to google

Comment: You seem to be very new to programming. You should probably get a beginner’s guide and read about if-then- and while-statements, basic comparison and such, basically the first 50 pages of any guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your technique:

```
a = [1,4,8,2,210,3]

newlist = []

while a:
    minimum = a[0]
    for x in a: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    newlist.append(minimum)
    a.remove(minimum)    

print (newlist)

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 210]
```

the code keeps removing the minimum from a and putting it into newlist, if you want it descending:

```
a = [1,4,8,2,210,3]

newlist = []

while a:
    maximum = a[0]
    for x in a: 
        if x > maximum:
            maximum = x
    newlist.append(maximum)
    a.remove(maximum)    

print (newlist)

#[210, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

if you want it in separate functions:

```
a = [1,4,8,2,210,3]

def ascending(data):
    newlist = []
    while data:
        minimum = data[0]
        for x in data: 
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
        newlist.append(minimum)
        data.remove(minimum)    
    return newlist

def descending(data):
    newlist = []
    while data:
        maximum = data[0]
        for x in data: 
            if x > maximum:
                maximum = x
        newlist.append(maximum)
        data.remove(maximum)    
    return newlist

a = ascending(a)
print ('Sorted in ascending order: ',a)

a = descending(a)
print ('Sorted in descending order: ',a)
```

simple program making use of min() and max() instead of going through the list one by one

```
def _sort(data,t):
    newlist = []
    if t == ('a'):
        while data:
            minimum = min(data)
            newlist.append(minimum)
            data.remove(minimum)
    elif t == ('d'):
        while data:
            maximum = max(data)
            newlist.append(maximum)
            data.remove(maximum)
    return newlist

def program():
    a=[]
    while True:
        print ('enter values to sort, type done when done')
        v=input('    >').lower().strip()
        if v == ('done'):
            break
        try:
            v = float(v)
            a.append(v)
            print ('numbers so far: ',', '.join(str(x) for x in a))
        except:
            print ('enter numerical value')
            continue

    while True:
        print ('enter "a" for sort ascending and "d" for sort descending')
        print ('enter "start" to go back to start')
        t=input('    >').lower().strip()
        if t == ('start'):
            program()
            return
        if not t == ('a') and not t == ('d'):
            continue
        a = _sort(a,t)
        print ('my sorted numbers: ',', '.join(str(x) for x in a))

program()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain to me what is function of "while",  why are we using it?

Comment: while data:  is a loop, it means while the data variable has things in it, when data is empty, e.g. data = []    (an empty list, or any variable for that matter) the loop stops running

Comment: If you are going to use `append` and `remove`, why not also use `min` or `max` and remove four lines and a loop?

Answer (score 0):

try making a new variable just to store temporary data and check in your if

```
for i in L:
    if i[i]<i[i+1]:
        temp = i[i]
        i[i] = i[i+1]
```

maybe loop through that a second time to recheck if its all in order